# Taxonomy terms language depending - why all languages are visible?

Tags: i18n-l10n, taxonomy-terms

What I want to acheive:
I have multilingual site (i18n module).

I have vocabulary named "brands" - terms of vocabulary don't need to be translated because they are the same in all languages.

I've also nodes that I can assign to languages and "brands".

In taxonomy - in multilingual options - I set this vocabulary to: `Localize. Terms are common for all languages, but their name and description may be localized.`

Now - the problem is - that when I enter from menu to "brands" and e.g. "volvo" in any language - all nodes (all translations in different languages) are shown.

I'd like to see only the nodes in language that is set.

I have other vocabulary - where terms should be translated also. I have set it to `Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated.` and there everything works fine - depending on language.

How to acheive that with my first vocabulary?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have set the vocabulary to `Translate. Different terms will be allowed for each language and they can be translated.` and duplicated each brand for each language and then updated each node - with setting term for particular language.

In my opinion this is workaround, but I couldn't find other solution.